# Quickly edit MS_Description in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, documentation

We document our database by storing descriptions for tables, columns, stored procedures etc. in the MS_Description extended property. It's easy enough to handle by scripting, but what I miss is some sort of a right-click command like "Document" on anything in the SSMS's object tree which would take you immediately to MS_Description (or its placeholder if it isn't yet created for that object).

You know, not "right-click -> properties -> extended properties -> type "MS_Description" -> type description text" but just "right-click -> Document -> type description text".

Anybody knows of an extension like this?
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest documenting the schema outside of the schema - then you have a much better chance at rebuilding in the event of a disaster, can show the schema model to developers etc. without giving them access to the database, etc. Imagine if instead of a separate piece of paper the instructions for putting together a shelving unit were printed on the bottom of each shelf.

Comment: As a developer, I've wanted to have a way to document each and every field, table, view, etc, directly in the database so I could easily refer to the documentation precisely without having to reference a third party.  I would love it if Microsoft supported the MS_Description property in a more native way.

Comment: Well, having comments on the objects directly doesn't mean we don't have anything else. We like MS_Description, because some add-ons are helpful enough to pop them up as tooltips and so on, directly in the SQL code (SQLPrompt from Redgate but maybe also some of the newer ssms versions now, not sure). Also, documenting while working in a team depends a lot on how conveniently and quickly you can input. That's to answer why MS_Description.

Comment: Well when you are using SSDT, you have the information in the source code as well. Sadly I feel that extended properties is another halve baked feature from MSFT, as many others. (right click on a table, select reports...., hint hint...)

Comment: I have a couple of things that can help - a free script that does bi-directional source-controllable text output https://gist.github.com/timabell/6fbd85431925b5724d2f and a paid product I'm working on that has one-click editing of the descriptions http://schemaexplorer.io/

Comment: In ssms you can edit the descriptions in a diagram by switching to full table view. I found out about this here https://dataedo.com/kb/tools/ssms/how-to-view-and-edit-table-and-column-comments